# No generar salto de línea final en CSV

Tags: fputcsv, salto-de-linea

tengo el siguiente código

```
    $lista = array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd');
    
    $fp = fopen('fichero.csv', 'w');
    
    foreach ($lista as $campos) {
        fputcsv($fp, $campos);
    }
    
    fclose($fp)
```

EL problema que tengo es que escribe bien la línea, y el puntero queda en la segunda línea generando una en blanco. No logro que no me escriba esta nueva línea.

Me orientan como resolverlo! Gracias